VBA: Row being pasted needs to all be in the same row, not look at last blank in that column
The VBA code I have currently pastes data into the last blank cell "End (x1Up). But in column C, there is often blank cells, so I need it to look column As last blank to know where it is pasting.
What is the best way to do this? what am I doing wrong?
Code:
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long, LstCol As Long
    
'   Set sheet objects

    Set ws1 = Application.Worksheets("FEL")
    Set ws2 = Application.Worksheets("Sustain")
    Set wsO = Application.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ws1.Range("P77:P500").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    
'   Find last rows in column D on each Source sheet

    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
'   Delete data from existing sheet

    wsO.Range("A1:O1000").ClearContents
    
' Copy data from each ws1 source sheet to Output sheet

    ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(76, "D"), ws1.Cells(lr1, "D")).Copy
    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(76, "E"), ws1.Cells(lr1, "E")).Copy
    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues""


It would be useful to see sample data, the expected outcome and what currently happens with your code.
